# How to reclassify a land classification rater?

Tags: qgis

I am creating a land cover raster using QGIS 3. I have developed a bunch of land classes but I would like to lump some features together to reduce the number of classes I have. I have been using a provincial forestry layer, canopy height models and a Depth to Water index. With these rasters,  I have been mapping out landcover/vegetation community data.

Each raster has the following codes (just giving examples, and not listing all of them).

**1 number codes (Land cover)**
1 - Agriculture
2-Barrens
3-Cutovers
4 - softwood Forests
5 - hardwood forests
6-mixedwood forests
7 - urban
8 ...etc etc.

**10 number codes (wetness class):**

0 - well drained soils
10 - poorly drained soils (wetland conditions)

**100 Height Classes**

100 - Herbaceous (0-1 m vegetation height)
200 - Regenerative/shrub (1 - 6 m vegetation height)
300 - Immature/young forests (6 - 11 m vegetation height)
400 - Mature forests (>11 m vegetation height)

I then added all rasters together using the Raster Calculator and for the most part, got results I wanted. For example:

415 - Mature Hardwood forested wetland
113 - herbaceous cutover wetland etc.

The issue is that in some cases I get values that don't make sense. For example, I may get a code such as 117 which would indicate a wet urban area. In cases like this, I would like to 'override' these values so all urban areas (regardless if wet or not) are grouped together.

I tried using the reclassify by table tool but it didn't seem to work. Most of my values will stay the same, I just want to change a select few.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[Reclassify by table](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgisreclassifybytable) is exactly what you need.
Here is how you could merge classes (pixel values) 1 and 5 to class 4. Make sure that you press `OK` and not `Back` (blue arrow), otherwise the results will not be saved:

[image]

Also make sure that you select the correct parameters (depends on your raster):

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to change any of the values for some reason. Do I have to type in all the values, even the ones that don't change? Or do I just need to type in the values that I need to change?

Comment: @Erioderma Only those that are needed. You may upload a small sample of your data for testing.